# Xamarin Essentials Geolocation extremely inaccurate locations

Tags: xamarin, geolocation

I am using the Geolocation functionality of Xamarin Essentials in my app as a foreground service running all the time and I have noticed on several devices that I sometimes (although rarely) get locations which are really far away from where they should actually be, looking like this:

[Location history with incorrect location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR8Lb.png)

For the location I set a timeout of 60 seconds and the best accuracy possible. The incorrect location on the screenshot has an `Accuracy` value of '8' but is much further away than 8 metres of the correct location.
This raises the following questions:

1. The location has the mentioned attribute `Accuracy` which refers to "horizontal accuracy". There is also an attribute `VerticalAccuracy` but it is not clear whether this refers to an y-Axis if the coordinates are seen on a plain or if it means accuracy of the altitude?
2. What could be the reason for this single location to have such bad accuracy? All other points with similar accuracy values are actually very accurate. In this case it was the last location to be tracked but it also happens sometimes during longer tracking sessions.
3. Is there any way to prevent this? I was thinking about implementing some level of statistical function to collect multiple points and get an average of them but that does not fix the root of the problem.

Comment: Have you set the `Location Mode` with High accuracy in your device settings?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT One device where we had the most inaccurate points actually did not have it on high but rather on GPS only. We will test again with the different settings to see if they are really the only cause of this happening.

Comment: Wait for your update.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I use "Improve Location Accuracy = on" I get a strange location about every 6 - 7 sec. With it off (using GPS only) no strange Locations.
S21+ with dual frequency GNSS/GPS.
But if I move to a new location the reported Location does not change until I get maybe 20yds from the 1st Location. It seems there is some threshold distance needed before a new value is reported.

Comment: Hi, Is this with an emulator, or a specific hardware device? Which emulator/device?

Answer (score 0):

Device Samsung Galaxy S21+ 5G which has Dual Frequency GPS/GNSS. Note that if I run the App "GPSTest" I do not see jumps in location and when I move I see the change in position in real time.